# How do I enroll a Wazuh Agent in my Wazuh Cloud environment?

Tags: agent, wazuh

I've setup a Trial environment in my Wazuh Cloud. Now I'm trying to enroll a Wazuh agent, but I don't know how to do that. I'm on windows 11 and I've installed the agent. After the installation, a window pops up named Wazuh Agent Manager. The window has 2 input fields: "Manager IP", which is pre-set to 0.0.0.0 and then "Authentication key". I have absolutely no clue where to find the correct Manager IP, nor the auth key. In Wazuhs own documentation it says that I can enroll an agent by following these steps:

1. Log into the Wazuh WUI.
2. Click the upper-left Wazuh icon and then Agents.
3. Click Deploy new agent.
4. Follow the steps described on the Deploy a new agent page.

When I click the upper-left Wazuh icon, there is no "Agents" anywhere to be found in the Web UI. I really don't know how to move on from here.